# A linear program with unbounded optimal solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Consider the following

$$\max 3x_1+x_2\\ s.t. -x_1+2x_2\le0\\ x_2\le4$$

a) Sketch the feasible region

b)Verify that the problem has an unbounded optimal solution value

**Attempt:**

a) (Here the region looks bounded but it's unbounded, sorry I don't know how to use Mathematica very well..) [image]

b) I tried to use the simplex algorithm but when taking the pivot column which was $[-1\ 0\  -3]^T$ and trying to divide by the other column (the last one of the tableu) $[0\ 4\ 0]^T$ I got $\frac{0}{-1}$ ,**4/0**,$\frac{0}{-3}$, I got a division by $0$.

What can I do here?

How can I do b) with this?

Could someone help me please?

Comment: @copper.hat ook.. sorry I don't get your point with noticing that the cost is $3t$ at the feasible point $(t,0)$

Comment: Sorry, it is part of the feasible region. You don't need Mathematica to solve this. Note that the value of the cost at the feasible point $(t,0)$ is $3t$ (with $t\ge 0$).

Comment: Check that if $t \ge 0$ that the point $(t,0)$ is feasible and the value of the cost is 3t, Therefore it is unbounded above. However, you are missing the part of the feasible region that is relevant to solving b).

Comment: @copper.hat oh so all your comments are making reference to a) ?

Comment: No. To show that the LP is unbounded you need to show feasible points that have unbounded cost. That is all I have done. It doesn't have an optimal solution in the usual sense.

Comment: @copper.hat mmh ok I don't understand your last comment, I though the simplex algorithm would help in the solution (I read a pdf about LP special-situations and it mentioned the simplex method as solution)

Comment: @Alt. you are not supposed to include nonpositive numbers in the ratio test. The fact no term is in the ratio test indicates unboundedness.

Comment: In any event, you don't need the simplex algorithm to show b).

Comment: @Alt.: My point is that you can find points that satisfy the constraints and have arbitrarily large value. Note that any point with $x_1 \ge 0$ and $x_2 = 0$ satisfies both constraints and so is feasible. Now choose $x_1$ as large as you want, then the cost is $3x_1$. You don't need an algorithm to find this.

Comment: @copper.hat got it, and how do I get an optimal from here?

Comment: @Alt.: It depends on what you mean. There is no $\max$ as you can make the cost as large as you want, so in some sense the optimum value is $\infty$, but there is no $(x_1,x_2)$ that attains that value, of course.

Comment: oh ok, thank you @copper.hat